# Postgresql Nested Foreach Int Array

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I was trying to do is, declare two arrays. 
One is for **invoice array** contains invoice id and that invoice's debt money,(for example [6238,236.0000]) 
The other one is for client's previous **recieved collections**.(for example client had 3 collections [62.000,40.000,10.000])

My tables are like these.

- Invoice Payments (Contains all payments for specific invoice and client)

  Total Numeric(18,4)
  InvoiceId integer
  Description character varying
  ClientId integer
  ...
  some other values too which is not important here.
- Invoice

  InvoiceId integer
  grandtotal numeric(18,4)
  ClientId integer
  InvoiceDate Date

  ...
  some other values too which is not important here.
- Client Movements

  ClientId integer
  CreatedDate Date
  Will numeric(18,4)

  ...
  some other values too which is not important here.

I tried to create a function with nested Foreach statements at PostgreSQL. Actually, this is going to be a trigger after insert, update, delete functions.

For testing purposes, I write as a function for now. So I get my _clientid and _clientmoveid manually.

```
 CREATE FUNCTION invoice_pay(_clientid int,_clientmoveid int) RETURNS int[]  AS $$
DECLARE _invoices varchar[] := (select  array_agg(DISTINCT '[' || inv.invoiceid || ',' || CAST (inv.grandtotal AS int) || ']') from invoices inv 
left join invoicepayments as ip on inv.invoiceid = ip.invoiceid where inv.clientid = _clientid group by inv.invoiceid,inv.grandtotal order by inv.invoicedate);
DECLARE _collections varchar[] := (SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT '[' || clm.will || ']') from clientmovements clm where clm.clientid = _clientid
 group by clm.createddate order by clm.createddate desc);


DECLARE _total numeric(18,4);
DECLARE _collectionTotal int;
DECLARE _invoicesArray int[];
BEGIN

/*first delete all the previous payments*/
DELETE FROM InvoicePayments where clientid = _clientid;



/*loop through all invoices and those remaining payments */
   /*first array contains invoiceid and invoicegrandtotal [6232,246.0000]*/
    FOREACH _invoicesArray SLICE 1 IN ARRAY _invoices
    LOOP
    /*loop throught all collections that client had. The second array contains only collections from client. [[15],[20],[40]]*/
           FOREACH _collectionTotal IN ARRAY _collections
           LOOP
            /*the total calculation is the if collection is bigger than the invoice grandtotal, close invoice as paid. Other than grandtotal minus collection*/
           _total := (case when _collectionsTotal > _invoicesArray[2] then _collectionsTotal else _invoicesArray[2] - collectionsTotal end);
            insert into invoicepayments(total,description,clientid,invoiceid)
    values(_total,'test',_clientid,_invoicesArray[1]);
           END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

RETURN _invoices;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After that function, i get an error like
 *invalid input syntax for integer: "{6328,236.0000}"*
Probably at some point, my array's first or second value does not work like I think. I use them like _invoicesArray[1] that. I want to take 6328 from _invoicesArray[1] value but it gives me an error. What should I do for nested foreach and what do I do wrong?

Comment: The problem is that `236.0000` is not a valid integer value. An integer can't have decimals, therefor the `.` is invalid in an integer value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually it gets it from {6328,236}. That means its even counts the curly brackets too. Not gets array first value = 6328. Gets complete array value.